# Ruby - Imap server connection gets disconnected after 2 days even after being reconnected every 25 minutes

Tags: ruby, imap

I login to IMAP server:

```
imap = Net::IMAP.new("imap.gmail.com")
imap.login("username", "password")
imap.select("inbox")
```

And then i use IMAP IDLE to fetch mails as and when they come. And since the imap server connection automatically gets disconnected after 30 minutes, i reconnect to the IMAP server every 25 minutes.

All this works fine until this goes on for more than 48 hours. I get the following error when i do **imap.logout**

The error message:

```
IOError closed stream - ["org/jruby/ext/openssl/SSLSocket.java:664:in `syswrite'",
"/opt/jruby-1.7.6/lib/ruby/shared/jopenssl19/openssl/buffering.rb:318:in `do_write'",
"/opt/jruby-1.7.6/lib/ruby/shared/jopenssl19/openssl/buffering.rb:415:in `print'",
/opt/jruby-1.7.6/lib/ruby/1.9/net/imap.rb:1210:in `put_string'", 
"/opt/jruby-1.7.6/lib/ruby/1.9/net/imap.rb:1182:in `send_command'", 
"/opt/jruby-1.7.6/lib/ruby/1.9/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'", 
"/opt/jruby-1.7.6/lib/ruby/1.9/monitor.rb:210:in `mon_synchronize'", 
"/opt/jruby-1.7.6/lib/ruby/1.9/net/imap.rb:1177:in `send_command'", 
"/opt/jruby-1.7.6/lib/ruby/1.9/net/imap.rb:352:in `logout'"
```

The imap object:

**#, raw_data="* OK Gimap ready for requests from 54.242.66.175 v74mb152689693qgv\r\n">, @mon_owner=nil, @client_thread=#, @tagged_response_arrival=#, @cond=#>, @sock=#>, @sync_close=true, @rbuffer="", @hostname="", @io=#, @sync=true, @wbuffer="RUBY0041 LOGOUTRUBY0042 LOGOUTRUBY0043 LOGOUTRUBY0044 LOGOUTRUBY0045 LOGOUTRUBY0046 LOGOUTRUBY0047 LOGOUTRUBY0048 LOGOUTRUBY0049 LOGOUTRUBY0050 LOGOUTRUBY0051 LOGOUTRUBY0052 LOGOUTRUBY0053 LOGOUTRUBY0054 LOGOUTRUBY0055 LOGOUT">, @tagno=55, @tagged_responses={}, @host="imap.gmail.com", @exception=nil, @usessl=true, @port=993, @tag_prefix="RUBY", @mon_count=0, @receiver_thread=#, @responses={"FLAGS"=>[[:Answered, :Flagged, :Draft, :Deleted, :Seen, "$Phishing", "$NotPhishing"]], "OK"=>[#, text=" Flags permitted.">, #, text=" UIDs valid.">, #, text=" Predicted next UID.">, #, text="">], "PERMANENTFLAGS"=>[[:Answered, :Flagged, :Draft, :Deleted, :Seen, "$Phishing", "$NotPhishing", :*]], "UIDVALIDITY"=>[651870578], "EXISTS"=>[1661], "RECENT"=>[0], "UIDNEXT"=>[1835], "HIGHESTMODSEQ"=>["288129"], "BYE"=>[#]}, @response_handlers=[], @continuation_request_arrival=#, @cond=#>, @receiver_thread_terminating=false, @logout_command_tag="RUBY0040", @debug_output_bol=true, @parser=#true, :Flagged=>true, :Draft=>true, :Deleted=>true, :Seen=>true, :*=>true}, @token=nil, @str="RUBY0040 OK 73 good day (Success)\r\n">, @mon_mutex=#, @idle_done_cond=#, @cond=#>>**

Can anyone explain why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

If the connection to the Imap server is already closed when you call the `logout` method, you'll get this error.

You can prevent this by checking the connection before doing the call

`imap.logout unless imap.disconnected?`

Hope this will help you.